# Why did Donald Trump say that?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, iraq, weapons

In an interview to CNN being held in 2007 related to the Iraq War, Trump said

"Saddam Hussein has nothing to do with World Trade Centre and also there's no weapons of mass destruction in Iraq for which Saddam is condemned"

But Saddam was accused of using Bio-weapons (weapons of anthrax..polio viruses) in Iran-Iraq war...and it has been in the record.

So what led Trump back in 2000s to say such things...and how much he differ now from his own perspective which he manifested in 2000s...?

Comment: "Why did he say a thing" tends towards generating an opinion based answer. Recommend "what justification did Donald trump have to say that" or similar.

Comment: @DrunkCynic  No buddy...that's not an opinion based answer. The title of the question becomes complete when u link it up with the complete body of the question.

Comment: I believe, it's a good question and hope to read some good answers.

Comment: Do you have a link to the interview?  If you're asking why he made a particular claim, it's because coalition forces found no biological weapons when they invaded in the 2000s. One of the main justifications for invasion was that he was supposed to have stockpiles ready to mobilize. Trump wasn't talking about the Iran-Iraq War was

Comment: Keep in mind the timeline - Iran/Iraq war ended in 1988. Gulf War was in 1991, Saddam ordered to disarm after that as part of the cease fire agreement.  Claims made in 2003 about him being armed.  That's more than 15 years after the end of the Iran/Iraq War and over a decade after he was ordered to end his WMD program. The statement and the facts don't necessarily conflict with each other.

Answer (score 7):

The claim wasn't that Hussein had never used weapons of mass destruction.  It was that Hussein did not have weapons of mass destruction at the time of the invasion.  Remember that the justification for the invasion was that Hussein was stonewalling UN inspectors and that the US had intelligence claiming that he had a supply of weapons of mass destruction.  As such weapons would be against his post-Kuwait treaties, that would have been a justification for an invasion.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraq_War):

> The Bush administration based its rationale for war principally on the assertion that Iraq possessed weapons of mass destruction (WMDs) and that Saddam's government posed an immediate threat to the United States and its coalition allies.

And later:

> After the invasion, no substantial evidence was found to verify the initial claims about WMDs. The rationale and misrepresentation of pre-war intelligence faced heavy criticism within the U.S. and internationally.

There are many statements that Trump has made of questionable veracity (e.g. about Ted Cruz's father or Barack Obama's citizenship).  That quote is not one of them.  That was actually a rather mainstream criticism of the (George W.) Bush administration.

Comment: One more thing I wanna ask...I hv been watching his campaigns and listening to his speeches...i feel that somewhr he sympathizes Iraq...In one of his speeches he said that Iran's gonna take control over Iraq and he opposed it..Plzz explain this or correct me if m wrong...

Comment: The pro-Iran political parties are currently strong in Iraq.  The general US concern is that a more influential Iran would support terrorism.  So it is concerning if other countries support Iran, as they might join in supporting terrorism.  This is also an angle of attack on Clinton, as she voted for the Iraq war as a Senator.  So Trump can blame bad or worrisome things in Iraq on her bad decision.  This hurts her with Sanders/Obama voters, as both of those were against the Iraq war.

Comment: I upvoted your answer but fail to see the relationship between Iranian influence in Irak and terrorism. It is not like Iran needs to control Irak territory or resources to support terrorist groups. AFAIK, the issue with Iran gaining control/influencing Irak is that it gives Iran more power and makes the Gulf monarchies (which historycally have had very bad relationships with Iran) uneasy.